# Approaches to generate auto-incrementing numeric ids in CouchDB

Tags: couchdb, auto-increment

Since CouchDB does not have support for SQL alike AUTO_INCREMENT what would be your approach to generate sequential unique numeric ids for your documents?

I am using numeric ids for:

- User-friendly IDs (e.g. TASK-123, RQ-001, etc.)
- Integration with libraries/systems that require numeric primary key

I am aware of the problems with replication, etc. That's why I am interested in how people try to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As Dominic Barnes says, auto-increment integers are not scalable, not distributed-friendly or cloud-friendly. It seems every app nowadays needs a mobile version with offline support, and that is not directly compatible with auto-increment integers. We all know this, but it's true: auto-increment integers are necessary for legacy code and arguably other stuff.

In both scenarios, you are responsible for producing the auto-incrementing integer. A view is running `emit(the_numeric_id, null)`. (You could also have a "type" namespace, e.g. by `emit([doc.type, the_numeric_id], null)`. Query for the final row (e.g. with a `startkey=MAXINT&descending=true&limit=1`, increment the value returned, and that is your next id. The attempt to save is in a loop which can retry if there was a collision.

You can also play tricks if you don't need 100% density of the list of IDs. For example, you can add timestamps to the `emit()` rows, and estimate the document creation velocity, and increment by that velocity times your computation and transmit time. You could also simply increment by a random integer between 1 and N, so most of the time the first insert works, at a cost of non-homogeneous ID numbers.

About where to store the integer, I think there is the *id* strategy and the *try and check* strategy.

The *id* strategy is simpler and quicker in the **short term**. Document IDs are an integer (perhaps prefixed with a type to add a namespace). Since Couch guarantees uniqueness on the `_id` field, you just worry about the auto-incrementing. Do this in a loop: `409 Conflict` triggers a retry, `201 Accepted` means you're done.

I think the major pain with this trick is, that *if and when* you get conflicts, you have two completely unrelated documents, and one of them must **be copied** into a fresh document. If there were relationships with other documents, they must all be corrected. (The CouchDB 0.11 `emit(key, {_id: some_foreign_doc_id})` trick comes to mind.)

The *try and check* strategy uses the default UUID as the `doc._id`, so every insert will succeed. Ideally, all or most of your inter-document relations are based on the immutable UUID `_id`, not the integer. That is just used for users and UI. The auto-incrementing integer is simply a field in the document, `{"int_id":20}`. The view of course does `emit(doc.int_id, null)`. (You can look up a document by integer id with a `?key=23?include_docs=true` parameter of the view.

Of course, after a replication, you might have id conflicts (not official CouchDB conflicts, but just documents using the same numeric id). The view which emits by ID would also have a reduce phase: simply `_count` should be enough. Next you must patrol the DB, querying this view with `?group=true` and looking for any row (corresponding to an integer id) which has a count > 1. On the plus side, correcting the numeric id of a document is a minor change because it does not require new document creation.

Those are my ideas. Now that I wrote them down, I feel like you must do relation-shepherding regardless of where the id is stored; so perhaps using `_id` is better after all. The only other downside I see is that you are permanently married to a fundamentally broken naming model—for some definition of "permanently."

Comment: Maybe, since there are so many questions about auto incrementing numbers, specifically related to couch db, the answer is for the developers to implement just that, a field that auto increments. Just sayin'

Comment: An auto-increment field is not possible in the CouchDB design. For example, CouchDB supports a 2-node CouchDB cluster, where one node is on Mars. (Or, more common, one node has a very slow or erratic Internet connection, for example in remote areas). There is no way to guarantee auto-increment in each location, since they might be out of communication. Often, people want auto-increment to get *unique* values, and for that a UUID works better. In other cases auto-increment can introduce security risks as well (people can guess each other's information). It is a design trade-off.

Answer (score 5):

Is there any particular reason you want to use numeric IDs over the UUIDs that CouchDB can generate for you? UUIDs are perfect for the distributed paradigm that CouchDB uses, stick with what is built in.

If you find yourself with any more than 1 CouchDB node in your architecture, you're going to get conflicting document IDs if you rely on something like "auto increment" when it comes time for replication. Even if you're only using 1 node now, that's probably not always going to be the case, especially since CouchDB works so well in a distributed and "offline" architecture.

Comment: I need short human-readable IDs. I do not care about scalability at the moment but I would prefer to avoid potential problems with replication

Answer (score 3):

I have had pretty good luck just using an iso formatted date as my key:

http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/IsoFormattedDateAsDocId

It's pretty simple to do, human-readable and it basically builds in a few querying options by just existing. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Keeping in mind the issues around replication and conflicts, you can use an update function to generate incrementing IDs that are guaranteed unique in a single master setup.

```
function(doc, req) {
    if (!doc) {
        doc = {
            _id: req.id,
            type: 'idGenerator',
            count: 0
        };
    }
    doc.count++;
    return [doc, toJSON(doc.count)];
}
```

Include this function in a design document like so:

```
{
   "_id": "_design/application",
   "language": "javascript",
   "updates": {
       "generateId": "function (doc, req) {\n\t\t\tif (!doc) {\n\t\t\t\tdoc = {\n\t\t\t\t\t_id: req.id,\n\t\t\t\t\ttype: 'idGenerator',\n\t\t\t\t\tcount: 0\n\t\t\t\t};\n\t\t\t}\n\n\t\t\tdoc.count++;\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\treturn [doc, toJSON(doc.count)];\n\t\t}"
   }
}
```

Then call it like so:

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:5984/mydb/_design/application/_update/generateId/entityId
```

Replace `entityId` with whatever you like to create several independent ID sequences.

Answer (score 2):

Not a perfect solution but something that worked for me. Create an independent service that generates auto-incremented ids. Yes, you probably say "this breaks the offline model of couchdb" but what if you get a pool of N ids that you can then use whenever you need to get a new auto-incremented id. Then every time you're online you get some more ids and if you are running out of ids you tell your users - please go online. If the pool is big enough (say the monthly traffic) this shouldn't happen. Again, not perfect but maybe can be helpful to some people.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of explicitly constructing an increasing integer key, you could use the implicit index couchDB accepts for paging.

The **skip** parameter accepts an integer that will effectively provide the auto-incrementing index you are used to.

http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Querying_Options

The drawback is that it is not a viable solution for "User-friendly IDs". The index is not tied to the doc, and is subject to change if you are rewriting history.

If your only constraint is "integration with libraries/systems that require numeric primary key", this will bridge the gap without loosing the benefits of couchDB's key structure.